# Android Screen Orientation size

Tags: android, android-orientation

I have created various layout resource files in order to ensure that my app supports all screen and devices sizes.

My problem is which one of the below is suitable to use in my AndroidManifest file. Once the user switches the device to landscape I would like Android to choose the landscape resource file instead of portrait.

```
android:configChanges="screenSize|keyboardHidden"


android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Which one is more suitable to use?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just create One extra folder in your `res folder` named `layout-land` and put all `landscape layouts` in this folder then operating system automatic show the layouts according device orientation.

No need to add anything `Manifest File`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `layout-land` for explicitly landscape layouts.

Answer (score 1):

**Android system** does it automatically. You don't need to put anything in your manifest.